# Astrophysical particle spectroscopy; narrow-line particle sources (charged or uncharged) for things other than photons? Have any been detected?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, spectroscopy, instruments, particles

- [Is Cosmic Ray Astronomy a thing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43527/7982)
- [Is there an equivalent of the red shift effect for cosmic rays?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43525/7982)

have got me thinking and under [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43526/7982) I've commented:

> That's a good point; there aren't as many energy peak-producing process for particles as there are for photons, especially at high energy. For low energies there's [alpha decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay) and [internal conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conversion)

That makes me wonder:

**Question:** Astrophysical particle spectroscopy; are there narrow-line particle sources (charged or uncharged) for things **other than photons?** Have any been detected? Have any instruments been built *anticipating* narrow peaks for things other than photons?

Comment: [Borexino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borexino) measured the ⁷Be neutrino line from the Sun